# 12.04 release end of life

Tags: 12.04

When Ubuntu desktop 12.04 hits the end of life is it still safe to use? I.e. is it still secure?

The reason i ask is because I can't upgrade to 16.04 as I'm on older AMD and amd catalyst is gone in the new release. I could upgrade to 14 but still have the same problem in a couple of years. 12.04 runs perfect on my hardware so don't want to upgrade. Any suggestions would be great. Thank you.

Comment: No, it's not safe and unsupported: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16823/eol-notice-precise-pangolin-12-04-will-be-end-of-life-starting-april-28-2017?cb=1

Comment: @CelticWarrior: Unless you want to pay for [extended support](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2017-March/000217.html).

Comment: Yes I thought that would be the case.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Indeed. However, someone hanging to an "older AMD" is extremely unlikely to purchase such service. A new and proper PC would be a wiser investment.

Comment: This is  a false problem anyway, the open-source `radeon` supports correctly most of the legacy hardware.

Comment: This is a bit off topic, but I've looked at other distros like Mint. Is it true the latest release of these are based on ubuntu 16? If so will these have the same issues with AMD. Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: Yes, it is and yes, same problem. Mint or any other non-official derivatives are off-topic here though. And any other distro that still supports the old fglrx driver **you don't want to use anyway** because they're running outdated kernels and/or X. Again, this is a **non-issue** because you don't need proprietary drivers.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, you answered my initial question and more. Peace